# i have a replace issue of certain text tag in php code

Tags: php

I have a php code where i want to replace {name} text to the location of file name under a folder. for example in the folder i have 4 files.

1. mallik-bazar-team-work.html
2. kolkata-team-work.html
3. delhi-team-work.html
4. agra-team-work.html

now i my php code its replace {name} to Mallik Bazar
But its change - to a space. but its also replace - to space in other text tag also. i want to replace it only on {name} tag.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$folderPath = 'folder location'; // Replace with the actual path to your folder

$files = scandir($folderPath);

foreach ($files as $file) {
    if (pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION) === 'html') {
        $filePath = $folderPath . '/' . $file;

        // Get the file name without the extension
        $fileName = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
        // echo $fileName;

        // Extract the first word before "-"
        $name = str_replace('-team-work', '', $fileName);

        // Read the contents of the file
        $fileContent = file_get_contents($filePath);

        // Replace "{name}" with the first word
        $updatedContent = str_replace('{name}', $name, $fileContent);
        
        $updatedContent = ucwords(str_replace('-', ' ', $updatedContent));

        // Write the updated content back to the file
        if (file_put_contents($filePath, $updatedContent) !== false) {
            echo "Successfully updated $file<br>";
        } else {
            echo "Failed to update $file<br>";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: How to did you expect the output file name? `mallik-bazar-team-work.html` into `mallik-bazar.html` like this?

Comment: "I have a php code" - please share it with us

Comment: Why don't you add the code directly to the question? [ask]

Comment: Clearly define your inputs and expected outputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is almost correct, but there's one issue. The `str_replace('-', ' ', $updatedContent)` line is converting all the `-` into `spaces` within the entire content of the file. If you want to convert `-` into space only in the {name} tag, you need to do it before replacing `{name}` in the content.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$folderPath = 'folder location';

$files = scandir($folderPath);

foreach ($files as $file) {
    if (pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION) === 'html') {
        $filePath = $folderPath . '/' . $file;
        $fileName = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
        $name = str_replace('-team-work', '', $fileName);
        $name = ucwords(str_replace('-', ' ', $name));
        $fileContent = file_get_contents($filePath);
        $updatedContent = str_replace('{name}', $name, $fileContent);

        if (file_put_contents($filePath, $updatedContent) !== false) {
            echo "Successfully updated $file<br>";
        } else {
            echo "Failed to update $file<br>";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

In this fixed code, `ucwords(str_replace('-', ' ', $name))` converts `-` into `space` only within the `$name` variable and then converts the first character of each word to uppercase. The modified `$name` is then used to replace `{name}` in the content.

This way, `-` is replaced with space only in the `{name}` tag and not anywhere else in the file content.

Comment: thanks for this suggestion sir. i will keep it in my mind. but sir in this code its also add extra s after the place name. for example if the file name is delhi-team-work.html then in that file its replace {name} to Delhis

Comment: now when i run the code its again replacing - in other text also. and after the name its adding s